# What can be said about the level set of the real part of an analytic function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I am cross-listing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703787/what-can-be-said-about-the-level-set-of-the-real-part-of-an-analytic-function) question from math.stackexchange since I did not find a satisfactory answer there. This is my first time posting a question on MO, so if this is not the appropriate community I apologize and can remove the question.

I am working with a function $F(z;a)$, for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $a$ being a set of parameters, from which I need to analyze the level set $\text{Re}(F(z))=0$ (for a fixed set of parameters $a$, which I will drop the notation now). The function $F$ is composed of elliptic functions and algebraic functions. To achieve my goal, I need to be able to say some concrete things about this level set. Here is what I know about the level sets right now:

1. The real line is always part of this level set.
2. The following symmetry exists: if $\text{Re}(F(z))=0$ then $\text{Re}(F(z^*))=0$ where $z^*$ is the complex conjugate of $z$.
3. There are 4 points in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ which are part of this level set (2 are conjugates of the other two). I can prove that the 2 conjugate points are endpoints of a "band" (arc) of the level set connecting the points.
4. The curve parameterized by $\text{Re}(F(z))=0$ has four saddle points at which $\textrm{d}(\text{Re}(F(z)))/\textrm{d}z = 0$. For some values of $a$, two of these saddle points are on the real axis and I can show that the bands mentioned in the previous item intersect this point.

I need to know more about this level set, in particular I would like to answer the following questions:

1. Can I prove that there are $n$ connected components of this level set? ($n$ might depend on $a$).
2. Is there any (nonreal) component of this level set outside of, for instance, the unit ball?
3. Is there reason to believe that any additional components of the set (not listed above) should be connected to those listed above ($\textit{i.e.}$ the real line or one of the 4 points)? Or, is there reason to believe that there should only be bands of the set branching off of the real line at saddle points?

Right now I am using software to get my hands on the geometry of this set. I have been looking at contour plots of $\text{Re}(F(z_r + i z_i))=0$ for different choices of $a$. The above questions are conjectures made from looking at different plots, but I know that the software misses things (for instance, it rarely shows the real line as being part of the desired set).

Help in the right direction would be appreciated, my knowledge of complex analysis theorems is woefully inadequate to accomplish my goal here. Any other ideas of what can be said (that I may have missed) would also be appreciated.

**Edit:** The expression was omitted originally because it is different in different contexts. 
By request, the expression for one of these cases has been added. It is:

$$F(z;a) = -2iz\omega_1 + 2\Gamma(\omega_1\zeta(\alpha;\Lambda) - \zeta(\omega_1;\Lambda)\alpha),$$
where $\Gamma = \pm 1$, $\zeta(\cdot;\Lambda)$ is the Weierstrass-zeta function defined on a rectangular lattice ($\omega_1\in \mathbb{R}, \omega_3\in i\mathbb{R}$) and $$ \alpha = \wp^{-1}(f(z;a); \Lambda)$$
where $f(z;a)$ has 4 branch points (corresponding to the 4 points mentioned in (3) above), has poles at $z=\infty$ and may also have poles at $z=0$. In general, $f(z;a)$ has points $\hat z$ and $\hat a$ such that $f(\hat z; \hat a) = 0$.

Comment: "Real part of analytic function" is equivalent to "harmonic function" and there seems to be an awful lot of literature on the level sets of harmonic functions.

Comment: Your $F(z)$ doesn't look like an entire function.  What singularities and branch points does it have?  If there are branch points, the level curves may depend on where you choose to put the branch cuts.

Comment: If $p$ is a zero of order $m$ of $F(z)-r$ where $r$ is real, $\text{Re}(F(z))=0$ will have $m$ smooth curves in a neighbourhood of $p$, intersecting at $p$ at angles $\pi/m$ if $m > 1$.  Similarly at a pole of order $m$ of $F(z)$ (but here the pole itself doesn't count as part of the level curve as $F$ is not defined there).

Comment: Welcome to MO! As to **my knowledge of complex analysis theorems is woefully inadequate to accomplish my goal here**, it is not about "complex analysis theorems". You just have a very special function (whose very definition will take me more than an hour to comprehend) whose behavior you have to unravel. Good luck, but I'm a bit pessimistic about your chance to get a meaningful answer from somebody who spends less than a week on this problem, so I apologize in advance if you get as much help here as on MSE...

Comment: You should specify more exactly what class of functions you consider. "Composed of elliptic and algebraic" is not sufficient. Are your functions single-valued? Holomorphic/meromorphic in what region?

Comment: **NateEldredge** thank you, this is true. Do you have a recommended source perhaps?

@RobertIsrael Thank you for the result! In the Edit you can see an example of such an F I am interested in. It has branch points  at the 4 values in my third point. The branch points are due to a square root of a quartic.

**fedja** Thank you for thinking about it to any extent, if I don't get an answer than so be it, no one owes it to me.

**AlexandreEremenko** See for example the problem I've given in the "Edit." I am interested in obtaining any result about the entire extended complex plane.

Comment: And where are the branch cuts?  Is the function analytic in a neighbourhood of $\infty$?  If $\infty$ is an essential singularity, there will be (besides the real axis) pieces of the level curve outside of any disk.  But I don't know, and it may be difficult to prove, whether these are new connected components.

Comment: The branch points are when $\Omega^2 = 0$. The branch cuts are along $\text{IM}(\Omega^2) = 0$ which goes through $\infty$. $\infty$ is not an essential singularity.